# Update an existing multi-volume archive with 7zip

Tags: archive, 7zip

I need to add a new file into a zip archive which has been split into volumes of 200mb each. Is there a way to add this file without unzipping it an zip it again?

I have these 3 parts

```
_default.zip.001
_default.zip.002
_default.zip.003
```

all of them creating `_default.zip` archive

and when I try to run

```
7z a -tzip .\_default.zip.001 some_file
```

I get

`ERRORS: Unexpected end of archive` 
since this is just one part of the actual archive.

Is this thing possible? If so, how?

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 0):

7z a -v300m  yourarchive2zip.7z files2zip

Comment: you can change "300m" to "300b 300g 300k"